# 2001 honda civic RPMs dropped to 0, car stalled

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission

Bought a 2001 honda civic about a week ago, put a new battery in it. It had very low idle, around 800. Driving at city speeds and suddenly the tachometer dropped to 0 and shortly after the car stalled. I was able to start it again and get it off the road, but the tachometer doesn't go above 0 when I start it, and it sounds like it's about to stall again. Any suggestions?

Comment: From those symptoms I'm inclined to say it might be an issue with the crankshaft position sensor, have you used a code reader?

Comment: That's kinda what I'm thinking as well. I'm going to run a code reader on it later this afternoon, thanks!